# How do I export this variable from class method to another file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, reactjs

1. Please go to line 60 or  (Variable name Amit inside the for loop) of this of this code, i want that variable name
   to exports in another file, but i  cannot use tat vairiable value to
   other file. when i do it by requiring it shows undefined.

   ```
   class FetchData {

       constructor(device_id, header) {
           this.device_id = device_id;
           this.header= header;
       }

       services() {
           // Get Device Details by deviceId
           return httpRequest({ 
               method  : 'get', 
               json    : true,
               url     : `${config.url.usermgmt_api}/device/${this.device_id}`,
               headers : { 'x-access-token': this.header }
           }).then( response => {
               if(response.hasOwnProperty('auth') && !response.auth) {
                   throw new Error(response.message);
               }
               let thingGreenLinks = [];

               // Current Active TG into the Array
               if(response.hasOwnProperty('mapping')) {
                   //We have to scroll through the mapping and return the shortcode and thingid and ports to connect
                   thingGreenLinks.push(response.mapping[0].TG_Port.split(/_/)[0]);    
               } else {
                   throw (response.message)? response.message : 'No mapping found. Device ID: '+ deviceid;
               }


               // Check mapping history 
               if(response.hasOwnProperty('map_history') && response.map_history.length > 0) {
                   response.map_history.reverse().map( record => { 
                       thingGreenLinks.push(record.mapping[0].TG_Port.split(/_/)[0]) 
                   })
               }
               return thingGreenLinks;
           }).then(async tg_ids => {
               logger.info('Fetching Hardware IDs of ThingGreen ...');
               let Hardware_IDs = [];

               for (let i = 0; i <= tg_ids.length - 1; i++) {
                   await fetchHardwareID(tg_ids[i], this.header)
                  .then( response => { Hardware_IDs.push(response.HardwareId) })

                  let Amit = 'amit'
                module.exports = { amit : Amit}

               }
               logger.info('Received Following Hardware IDs :\n'+Hardware_IDs.join('\n'));
               return Hardware_IDs;
           })
           .catch( err => Promise.reject(new Error(err.message)));
       } } exports.FetchData = FetchData;
   ```

   1. List item

Comment: Hi Amit, welcome to Stackoverflow :) The tags you added are a bit extensive.. Please only add the tags related to the question. (angularjs, angular, reactjs are pretty conflicting aswel)

Comment: Hi Amit, Welcome. Can you please post the code where you are importing this? The scope of `Amit` is only with in `services()`. The Exports are always done at the end of file.

Comment: [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) is a good read if you have problem with formatting.

Comment: Amit, I think it's better aproach has a variable in the service and use (this.Amit="amit"), All your component that inject hte service can acess to the variable. Or pehaps you want to "emit" the variable to an observable  see https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service (then, all yours component that subscribe to the Observable receive the variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have a variable in your class and 
  assign a value to it inside your services function

```
class FetchData {

    constructor(device_id, header) {
        this.device_id = device_id;
        this.header= header;
        this.amit = "";
     }

   services() {
       //your sevices code
       this.amit='amit'
     }


} exports.FetchData = FetchData;
```

then in another file where you are importing FetchData,you can access it with object.varible name.

```
    var fetchDataObject = new FetchData(device_id, header);
     fetchDataObject.amit //this is your variable amit
```